# kgdb shows No source available

Tags: linux-kernel, kgdb

I am debugging a kernel module with kgdb.With kgdb I am able to hit the breakpoints on the required function but the tui interface shows

No source available.

Also putting breakpoints on particular line number does not works. When i am trying to put breakpoints on particular line number following message is displayed on gdb interface.
"No line N in <file_name>.c"

Attached is the image.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWFEi.png)

1. I tried putting breakpoints on particular line number in file. Used the following command.

   (gdb)break <file_name>.c:line_number

   (gdb)No line <line_number> in file "<file_name>.c".

   (gdb)Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) `

`2) I tried putting breakpoint on particular function. Used following command.

(gdb)break <function_name>

result: breakpoint hits but KGDB tui interface shows No source
available

Comment: Maybe you need to point GDB to your sources, by configuring it in run-time. It might be starting at static paths rather than local ones for your sources. [This might help you](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb.html/Source-Path.html)

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded ubuntu from 18.04 to 20.04 and now i am able to hit the breakpoints with source code available in tui interface.
Not sure,Looks like there was some issue with 18.04 release.